# Comparing Chebychev's inequality to the exact probability

Tags: probability, integration

Let $X$ be continuous with pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$ if $0<x<\infty$, and zero elsewhere.

$(1)$ Use Chebychev's inequality to obtain a lower bound on $P(-1.5<x<3.5)$

Here's what I did:

$$P[|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma]\le \frac1{k^2}$$

$$1-P(|X-1|\gt 2.5)\ge 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{2.5^2}$$

$$\sigma^2= E(x^2)-E(x)^2$$

$$E(x)=\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx$$

$$=[-e^{-x}(x+1)]_0^{\infty}=1$$

$$E(x)^{2}= 1^2=1$$

$$E(x^2)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-x}dx$$

$$=[-e^{-x}(x^2+2x+2]_0^{\infty}=2$$

Thus,

$$\sigma^2=2-1=1$$

Finally,

$$1-P(|X-1|\gt 2.5)\ge 1-\frac{1^2}{2.5^2}=.84$$

I'm not too uncomfortable with that part, but there may be a mistake in there. I'm new to this stuff.

$(2)$ Compare this bound to the exact probability. Here is where the trouble sets in. When I try to find:

$$P(-1.5<x<3.5)=\int_{-1.5}^{3.5}e^{-x}dx$$

I get a value much larger than $1$ (which obviously cannot be as it needs to be between $0$ and $1$). My question is, how do we take that negative into account when we try to find that probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf is zero on $[-1.5,0]$. Thus, you only need to integrate from 0 to 3.5.

Comment: You know, I really ought to see those coming.